# MySQL function which takes a set of strings?

Tags: sql, mysql

There's a mysql function which works like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE name ???('bob', 'jane', 'sally')
```

The above query should return all records where name is bob, jane, or sally. Where it says ??? above is where the function name should be.

Can anyone remind me what that function is called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE name IN ('bob', 'jane', 'sally')
```